# How to View an Array Element by Its ID Angular

Tags: angular

I have created an array and displayed in the homepage component, Now I want to when I click one of the Images, I want to get the details of that element on the item details component, how to do that? thank you!

**[homepage component view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1iOY.png)**

**homepage component code**

Button Click

```
<a (click)="viewItem(i)" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">More Details</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the index when assigning the `*ngFor` so it can be passed to your click handler.

Assuming some markup here...

```
<div *ngFor="let car of cars; let i = index">
  ...
  <a (click)="viewItem(i)" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">More Details</a>
</div>
```

Then you can access the item in the array by index.

Comment: I have done that part, I got the onclick element. Now I want to pass it to another component and display in HTML. that's the thing I am struggling.

Comment: See: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

I think you also able to pass direct car detail inside the function Argument

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let car of cars; let i = index">
  ...
  <a (click)="viewItem(car)" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">More Details</a>
</div>
```

TS

```
viewItem(car){
console.log(car);
}
```

Comment: I have done that part, I got the onclick element. Now I want to pass it to another component and display in HTML. that's the thing I am struggling.